# spark on yarn cluster creates a spark job with the number of workers that is much smaller than what is specified in the spark context

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

Spark on yarn cluster creates a spark job with the number of workers that is much smaller (only 4 workers) than what is specified in the spark context (100):
here is how I create the spark context and session:

```
config_list = [
    ('spark.yarn.dist.archives','xxxxxxxxxxx'),
    ('spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON','xxxxxxxxx'),
    ('spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON','xxxxxxxxxxx'),
    ('spark.local.dir','xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
    ('spark.submit.deployMode','client'),
    ('spark.yarn.queue','somequeue'),
    ('spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors','100'),
    ('spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors','100'),
    ('spark.executor.instances','100'),
    ('spark.executor.memory','40g'),
    ('spark.driver.memory','40g'),
    ('spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead','10g')
]

conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAll(config_list)

spark = SparkSession.builder.master('yarn')\
    .config(conf=conf)\
    .appName('myapp')\
    .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
```

would appreciate any ideas

Comment: Even if you specify the min executors as 100, if your cluster only has 4 total nodes (including master and worker), it will not be able to specify 100 executors.

Comment: I agree with Ashwin Agrawal. It would be useful to specify how many nodes the cluster has in total, and how many cores and how much memory each node has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spark session will allocate maximum amount of free worker nodes available at the time of running of your job if you specify the minimum worker nodes to be greater than equal to your actual workers/executors present in your cluster.

You can also verify this by seeing the number of executors allocated in the session by using below:

```
sc._conf.get('spark.executor.instances')
```

I hope you understand

Comment: I see, it looks indeed that with the time my spark job on the cluster gets dynamically allocated more workers. What is strange though, is that even if the job gets more workers the max number of concurrent jobs/processes seems to stay fixed at only 4 (the number of workers that was available at the beginning when I started the job). Is there a way to also dynamically adjust the max number of the concurrent processes for a job on the spark/yarn cluster such that it gets increased as the number of workers increases?